# Number of solutions $\text{mod}\;p$ for all $p$ and Betti numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a projective scheme over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$.
 Suppose we know the number of solutions of $X$ mod $p$ for (almost) all prime $p$, can we find out the Betti numbers of the complex manifold associated to $X$?